# A countdown timer that minimises to tray?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for a countdown timer software that minimises to tray while running and thus hiding any active window.

I am very fond of [Tea Time](https://launchpad.net/~teatime), however, it does not minimise to tray and keeps an active window while running.

Some potential ideas (thanks Rinzwind):

- Add a countdown feature that sits in the panel and keeps counting down)
- Optionally even residing in the launcher and having an icon go 10,9,8...,1,"beep" (that's actually what Tea Time does)

Comment: @Rinzwind you want me to add your ideas to the question?

Comment: Cool! Added your ideas. :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a look at Alarm Clock. It is an alarm clock and a timer and minimise to tray.

**Installation**: `sudo apt install alarm-clock-applet`

Comment: This is cool! Do you have a recommendation for a good default alarm clock sound?

Comment: I like glass but you have to try and find one you like

Comment: Confirmed working with the newest Ubuntu 18.04. Once installed, hit `super` and look for "Alarm Clock".

Comment: Perfect. Just a note - in order to display the timer in the tray, tick the preference "show time label"

Comment: Looks like this won't be in 20.04 according to [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=alarm-clock-applet).

Comment: It does not work in 20.04. I am now using gnome-clocks. No minimize to tray, but if you close it, it remains active.

Comment: I downloaded the deb file straight from ubuntu. It works perfectly on 20.04.

Answer (score 14):

I'm pretty sure that is not what the OP expects, but anyways I like it:

**The nerd solution**

```
nohup sleep 60 && notify-send Timer "Time up" && paplay /usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo/complete.oga &
```

I have to add a way to notify how much time is left ..

Comment: How can I run this in tray? I assume I need an open terminal window?

Comment: You run this in terminal and can then close the terminal. No tray at all, but also no active window.

Comment: OK. With the recent edit of the Question, this answer doesn't fit anymore. I would like to leave it here because I like it and maybe helps others.

Comment: @RoVo If I understand correctly, this does *not* work. You need to wrap everything from `sleep` to `complete.oga` in single quotes. Otherwise, the `notify-send` bit would run immediately, as `nohup` would only apply to the `sleep 60` command.

Comment: @pLumo works like a charm. can you suggest a way to have it triggered EVERY 60s?